# Increasing the width of a nested (ul ul ul li) drop down nav list item

Tags: html, css, list

Here is my site:
http://www.simply-a-christian.com/index.html

On the nav bar, if you move to:

- Beliefs

  - Marian Dogmas

you can see that the text in the list item of each Marian Dogma (there are four listed) is wrapped. I'd like to increase the width of each of the four individual list items so that the text of the list item is in a single line. How do I accomplish this?

https://jsfiddle.net/H3br3wHamm3r81/aq8au39v/

HTML

```
<ul>    
<li><a href="beliefs.html" title="Beliefs">Beliefs</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas.html" title="Marian Dogmas">Marian Dogmas</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/assumption_of_mary.html" title="Assumption of Mary">Assumption of Mary</a></li>
            <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/immaculate_conception.html" title="Immaculate Conception">Immaculate Conception</a></li>
            <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/mother_of_god.html" title="Mother of God">Mother of God</a></li>
            <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/perpetual_virginity.html" title="Perpetual Virginity">Perpetual Virginity</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Stylesheet may be found in link above.

Comment: It's weird because under "Beliefs," the list item "Seven Sacraments of the Christian Faith" does not wrap, and I never defined white-space: nowrap property for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space` and remove the `float` for the particular unordered list by using a custom class like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="listCustom">
    <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/assumption_of_mary.html" title="Assumption of Mary">Assumption of Mary</a></li>
    <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/immaculate_conception.html" title="Immaculate Conception">Immaculate Conception</a></li>
    <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/mother_of_god.html" title="Mother of God">Mother of God</a></li>
    <li><a href="beliefs/marian_dogmas/perpetual_virginity.html" title="Perpetual Virginity">Perpetual Virginity</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.listCustom li  {
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: none;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/aq8au39v/2

Comment: Hmm, unless I'm doing something wrong, it's not working... But, you're right, it definitely has something to do with white space.

Comment: By the way, I'm testing it by using the files on my PC's local hard drive first, before I upload to my web host.

Comment: Use inspect element on your webpage and add the above to one of the `li` items to see the change. I tried the above on your site just now and it seems to be working fine :) If it works on browser using inspect element, then you must have added the css wrong

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/aq8au39v/2/

Comment: I named the ul class "tertiary," i.e. <ul class="tertiary">. I also inputted the same text in the style.css stylesheet except it has .tertiary li instead of .listCustom li. It's still not working. I must be overlooking something obvious. Any ideas? Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/H3br3wHamm3r81/8r5gkj0p/

Comment: Remove the `nav` from `nav.tertiary li` and just leave it as `.tertiary li`

Answer (score 0):

By adding this style you prevent all menu items to break, including the Maria dogmas:

```
header nav li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You may still add explicit breaks by adding a `<br>` tag in the text. 
Also you may want to consider adding a special class, like `menu` to the nav element that contains the menu. Otherwise this style may affect other navigation block you may want to add later.